# SoudPlayer plays the same file again and again

Tags: c#, audio

I am doing recording in my application using C#.

I record voice to the same file and play it but the SoundPlayer plays the contents recorded first time.

For example I have file `test.wav` where I record `"hello"` and then I record `"hi"` to the same file

by overwriting the file. When I play the file `test.wav` player plays `"hello"`.

I have only one instance of player, e.g.

```
public static System.Media.SoundPlayer Player;      

static void Main()
{           
    try
    {
        Player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Code for playing the file:

```
public static void Play(string fileName)
{
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        Program.Player.SoundLocation = fileName;
        Program.Player.Load();
        if (Program.Player.IsLoadCompleted)
        {
            Program.Player.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what is wrong here.

Comment: "_I don't know what is wrong here._" - And you will never will, as long as you are catching and ignoring all the valuable exceptions.

Comment: Where's the code where you actually load and play the file?

Comment: so any exceptions? what about the recording method?

Comment: @UweKeim: try/catch is only when I am creating the Player.

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra code. Is that entire Play function getting called each time you write the new file to disk?

Comment: @Tim: Yes, this function is called when I want to play the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the Setter for the `SoundLocation` property is an interesting check:

```
set
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        value = string.Empty;
    }
    if (!this.soundLocation.Equals(value))
    {
        this.SetupSoundLocation(value);
        this.OnSoundLocationChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

You can see that it looks to see if the new location differs from the old one. If it does, then it does some setup work. If it doesn't, it essentially does nothing.

I'm betting you can get around this by doing something like this:

```
public static void Play(string fileName)
{
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        Program.Player.SoundLocation = "";
        Program.Player.SoundLocation = fileName;
        Program.Player.Load();
        if (Program.Player.IsLoadCompleted)
        {
            Program.Player.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

The first call to the `SoundLocation` setter would clear out the loaded stream. The second one would then set it up properly with the location again and allow for `Load` to load the stream as expected.

Comment: Thanks, that helped, do you know why some wise minds down voted me for this question ? Strange people all around...

Comment: People are quick with the downvote sometimes. But in general it helps to make sure your question is well-formed and complete when you initially post it (all relevant code included, for instance).